# Send simple email from VB.net

Tags: vb.net, email

I usually send email using a full-featured library (Chilkat) but I want to try to compose the email manually to examine differences.  I'm using this for starters:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Dim mail As New MailMessage()
mail.From = New MailAddress("MyMail@Gmail.com")
mail.To.Add("MyMail@yahoo.com")
mail.Subject = "Test1 "
mail.IsBodyHtml = False
mail.Body = "This is a test."

Dim smtpServer As New SmtpClient
smtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("MyMail@Gmail.com", "MyMailPWD")
smtpServer.Port = 465
smtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
smtpServer.EnableSsl = True
smtpServer.Timeout = 3000
smtpServer.Send(mail)

MsgBox("The mail Is sent!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
```

But I keep getting a timeout error on the Send command.  The credentials are all good because it works fine using Chilkat.  I also know that I am reaching smtp.gmail.com because it's not happy if I switch to port 587.  How can I get a detailed report of the exchange for debugging purposes?  Thanks.

Comment: You can show respect for those who might help you by making the basic effort to ensure your code sample is well-formatted, instead of indented way to the right.

Comment: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4Np5xijwRvjoHySydWOhuh52VDVDjF2a2o3-E401bIA7tM5tuCdWOHrqGNgz0RqQk_JMcDpqcEmYwxN7puRHV6wsbYOqw

Comment: Sorry about that Joel.  When I looked at the post in the preview box, it looked like the fit was nice.  Noted for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail no longer allows basic SMTP access by default. It used to be you could get around this by enabling a "Less Secure Apps" option, but [now this is gone, too](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en), or soon will be (certain types of accounts are phasing this out more slowly, but it IS going away).

Instead, you have to use a modern authentication mechanism like OAuth, or [create a per-App password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833).

Comment: You're absolutely right and I forgot about that in doing this latest test.  So although it's true that this test with gmail was downright ridiculous of me, the issue still occurs no matter what credentials I put in.  IOW, if I replace by mail.From = New MailAddress("MyMail@mydomain.com"), smtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("MyMail@mydomain.com", "MyMailPWD") and smtpServer.Host = "mail.mydomain.com", I still get the timeout error.  Again, is there any way to view the comm exchange for debugging purposes?  Thanks!

Comment: I'd either need to use something like wireshark or check the logs on the server, though I wouldn't be surprised to learn Visual Studio has a network audit built in somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Chilkat allows you to inspect all the details if you simply display the LastErrorText property.
Documentation: https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/vbnetMailManRef.html#prop29

***The Basic Concept of LastErrorText***
There are a few important things about the LastErrorText:

1. Each Chilkat method call (or property access) clears the LastErrorText and writes new information about what transpired during the method call.  This information is available regardless of the success/failure of the method call.  Most Chilkat objects include a VerboseLogging property that controls whether more or less information is recorded.  Only use VerboseLogging for debugging situations as it may impact performance.  (Note: Some property accesses will not write anything to LastErrorText because the internal implementation is trivial and it could adversely affect performance, especially if the property is used in a “for” loop statement.)

Comment: As indicated in my original post, I'm trying to send an email without using Chilkat in order to test something in this particular case.  But thanks for your contribution and your time!

Comment: The idea is to use the same exact settings with Chilkat. Most likely, it would also fail but provide you with detailed error info that would pinpoint the problem.